# Upload image file to PHP script from a c# app

Tags: c#, php

I am trying to upload a jpeg image from my winform app to a PHP script.

This is my C# code:

```
public static long Upload(string filePath, string serverUrl)
{
    long fileSize = new FileInfo(filePath).Length;
    using (WebClient uploadClient = new WebClient())
    {
        uploadClient.Headers.Add("Content-Type", "binary/octet-stream");
        byte[] result = uploadClient.UploadFile(serverUrl, "POST", filePath);
        string test = System.Text.Encoding.ASCII.GetString(result);
    }
    return fileSize;
}
```

This is my php script:

```
<?php

if (isset($_FILES['file'])  && is_uploaded_file($_FILES['file']['tmp_name']))
    if (move_uploaded_file($_FILES['file']['tmp_name'], 'frame.jpg'))
        exit("File Uploaded");

echo exit("File Not Uploaded");
```

when the c# app runs, the request is made to the PHP script and I am getting a response back: *File Not Uploaded*

I tried to dump the `$_POST` on the script when the upload request is made and it's always empty.

Any idea why it's failed to upload?

Comment: What do you see when you dump the contents of the $_FILES array? Still empty? I'm wondering if 'file' is the correct index into that array.

Comment: Already did that, yes it's still empty.

Comment: Also when using forms in php to upload files, they indicate in their docs to use a content type of "multipart/form-data". Not sure if that will make a difference either.